# Asp.net Link Button is not firing in Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

I have asp.net link button in Update Panel :

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelWindMit">
 <ContentTemplate>
     <table>
     <tr>
       <td id="tdWindMitInspectDt1" runat="server" align="left" width="20%" class="labelTD"
                                                        style="padding-top: 5px">    
         <div style="overflow:hidden;width: 35%;padding-top: 10px;">
             <asp:LinkButton id="WindMitResetDefaults" Cssclass="buttonblue"  runat="server" OnClick="WindMitResetDefaults_ServerClick" >                          
                   <span>Reset</span>  <asp:LinkButton>                                                                   
          </div>
      </td></tr>
      <tr id="trhideDate2" runat="server">
       <td>
         <div style="overflow:hidden;width: 88%;padding-top: 10px;">
           <asp:LinkButton id="WindMitResetDefaults2" class="buttonblue"  runat="server" href="javascript:void(0);" OnClick="WindMitResetDefaults_ServerClick"> 
              <span>Reset</span>
           </asp:LinkButton>                                                  

         </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
 </ContentTemplate>
 </UpdatePanel>
```

In my code

```
   Protected Sub WindMitResetDefaults_ServerClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles WindMitResetDefaults.Click //Not Firing to this event handler

  End Sub
```

I not understanding what I am doing wrong, can any one help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have used only one `<form>` tag

Comment: I have one form tag

Comment: Can you please your **Inherits** and **Code file** attributes whether it's pointing to the correct names @DotNetDeveloper